# How to structure collaborative notes in HTML

Tags: html, comments, semantic-markup, annotate

In our CMS system we will add a feature where users can add notes to the existing content. This annotation-like system is to help users each other writing good texts. The system is inspired by the way [medium](https://medium.com/about/8304190661d4) and [substance](http://substance.io/) work, but Microsoft Office, Libre Office and Google Drive have the same feature.

The notes itself will be stored in a database, where the notes have an author and can contain some meta-data. However, the notes must be attached to (a selection of) words. In our case we have a very simple HTML WYSIWYG editor, so I was thinking to add some "special" markup to the contents:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <note ref="4">consectetur</note> adipiscing</p>
```

And in our database there is a note stored with an identifier `4`.

I came up with this method because you can't simply attach it to a string position or something. I am wondering, is this in general the good/best method? What is common to do?

The WYSIWYG editor should not filter out the `<note>` tag, but in the rendering at the frontend the tag must be removed. Are there options which are smarter than this?